# Getting multiple URLs from request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been trying to get multiple urls using requests.get

Here is my code:

```
import requests
links=['http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170117.txt','http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170118.txt']
   for url in links:
     for number in range(1,10):
       page = requests.get(url+str(number))
       print(page.text)
```

Unfortunately, it does not generate me with any results.

Would anyone mind helping me out?

Comment: what kind of url do you want to get?

Comment: You are trying to get `http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170117.txt1` which does not exist

Comment: Hi, it is more like a .txt file (e.g. http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170118.txt)

Comment: @OrangeEfficiency why use for loop to concat url?

Comment: Why are you adding a number on the end of the URL?

Comment: @DannyCullen , oh, cos the end number from the link increases by 1 (20170117 to 20170118)

Comment: You need to explain clearly what you are trying to achieve? what are your expected results?

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I just wanna extract the contents from those two text files.

Comment: thanks, I want to get all the contents from those two files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import requests
links=['http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170117.txt','http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170118.txt']
for url in links:
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page.text)
```

remove the for loop.

out:

```
Date|Symbol|ShortVolume|ShortExemptVolume|TotalVolume|Market
20170117|A|185680|1576|584041|Q
20170117|AA|203741|929|406062|Q
20170117|AAAP|3133|0|13594|Q
20170117|AAC|39417|0|63472|Q
20170117|AADR|1311|0|2627|Q
20170117|AAL|854774|5778|1580018|Q
20170117|AAMC|4450|0|6008|Q
20170117|AAME|3636|200|7186|Q
20170117|AAN|66111|200|118626|Q
20170117|AAOI|359275|1600|603069|Q
20170117|AAON|12291|0|31544|Q
20170117|AAP|71928|0|169905|Q
20170117|AAPL|2935502|68038|9269269|Q
```

Answer (score 2):

To just extract the data you do not need the number range loop

```
import requests
links=['http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170117.txt','http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170118.txt']
for url in links:
   page = requests.get(url)
   print(page.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like so:

```
import requests

links=['http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170117.txt','http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20170118.txt']

with open('path_file17', 'w') as f1, open('path_file18', 'w') as f2:
    f1.write(requests.get(links[0]).content)
    f2.write(requests.get(links[1]).content)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Sorry I was not clear on my question. Basically, I just wanna extract the contents from those two text files.

Comment: Ok you can get it simply. What after that? Store it list? Do analysis with pandas?

Comment: I just wanna store them in a txt file first, then later do regression analysis using stata

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: @OrangeEfficiency Give the path and filename in `open()` function.